# Unresolved reference: font in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, fonts

I am trying to set a font to a text view in android studio but for some reasons, I cannot access the font directory.

I get **Unresolved Reference: font**

What I did

**-**  Created a new directory by right clicking res > new > Android Resource Directory > Directory name : font > Resource type : font

**-** Placed my font in that directory, so the directory reads - **res/font/myfont.ttf**

**-** In my fragment I tried to access the font like this

```
var typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.myfont.ttf)
```

Error shows **Unresolved Reference: font**

I tried to rebuild project but still not working.

Comment: `typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.myfont)`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

> typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(),
> R.font.myfont)

Do not add `.ttf`extension.

Comment: Thank you. Although, I had to delete the imported R class and import my own projects R class. As the imported one couldn't reference the font directory,

Answer (score 2):

> public static Typeface getFont (Context context,
> int id)

Returns a font Typeface associated with a particular resource ID.

Try with

```
typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.myfont)
```

FYI - Read officials guideline about [**`Fonts in XML`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in the res/font/ folder to bundle fonts as resources. These fonts are compiled in your R file and are automatically available in Android Studio. You can access the font resources with the help of a new resource type, font. For example, to access a font resource, use **`@font/myfont`**, or **`R.font.myfont`**.

**NOTE**

You can call custom font ttf/otf directly. Use [**`createFromAsset`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface#createFromAsset(android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String))

```
 val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(requireContext().assets,"font/myfont.ttf")
```

Comment: This is all true, but it doesn't address the question.  The problem comes from importing Android.R.  Look at the other answer from Ibramazin.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that:

- *"R"* class imported was the framework resource "**android.R**"
- I had to delete that and import My project *"R"* class **"com.myproject.project.R"**

And call like this

- `val typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.poppings)`

No error again.